# Error while using curly braces initialization in a move constructor (C++)

Tags: c++, initialization, move

Consider a simple class with a move constructor:

```
class Entity{
private:
    char* buf;
    int size;
/.../

public:
Entity(Entity&& other):
    size{other.size}, buf{other.buf}
    {
        other.size{0};
        other.buf{nullptr};
    }
};
```

While compiling this, I get an error on `other.size{0};` that says: expected ";" before "{" token.
If I change the initialization to the "old-styled" one: `other.size = 0;  other.buf = nullptr;`, the code compiles. I tend to use list-initialization everywhere just to be consistent, but why does it produce an error in this case?

Comment: Initialisation happens either implicitly or in the constructor's initialisation list (the part after the `:`).  Inside the constructor initialisation has already happened and you need to use assignment eg  `other.size = 0;`.

Comment: `other.size` was initialized when `other` was created. Changing its value is not initialization; it's assignment.